# What is the purpose of having two overloaded operators for const and non const object

Tags: c++, constants, operator-overloading, raytracing

I'm struggling to understand some code from "Ray Tracing in One Weekend" chapter 3.1.

We have a 3d vector class defined, and are overloading some operators.
The following two lines confuse me:

```
        double operator[](int i) const { return e[i]; }
        double& operator[](int i) { return e[i]; }
```

From what I understand the first line runs when the object is a const and returns e[i] by value.
The second line runs when the object is not const and returns e[i] by reference.
What is the point in doing this?
I think there's some potential for speedup by using references to mutable objects instead of returning them by value. Are there any other reasons?

Comment: `vec[0] = 5.0;`

Comment: above vs `auto x = vect[0]`. Depending if `vec` is `const` or not, first one will compile or not, second will always work.

Comment: `double & temp = vec[0];
 temp = 5.0;` you can update the vector using a reference. (as above too)

Answer (score 1):

When the operator returns by non-const reference, the value can be modified by the caller. Normally, the const version would return const reference, but in case of `double`, returning by value is just as fast.

Answer (score 1):

A non-‘’’const’’’ function can only be called on a mutable object. A const function can be called on either a ‘’’const’’’ or non-‘’’const’’’ object, but will default to the mutable function.
The mutable function allows the object to access a reference the double value (therefore it can be modified). The ‘’’const’’’ function lets a const object access the double value; it returns a value because it cannot modify the object.
It is unlikely to have any performance impact; both a reference and a double are likely to have 64 bits (on a modern desktop), although this is an implementation detail and will likely be optimized as needed by the compiler anyways.